# Unable to get an object value using get method in Django

Tags: python, django

I want to get an object value from a model. After trying the get() method, I've been unable to make it work.And I'm getting the below error. I have a page that display the name of a place to users, so if a user see a place he likes, he will go ahead and fill the form.And in the form, I want to get the name of the place automatically from another model, I don't want users to fill the name of the place. Below are my codes

```
       NameError at /welcome/

       global name 'name' is not defined
```

Models

```
 class Fin(models.Model):
      user=models.ForeignKey(User)
      name=models.CharField(max_length=100)

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.user


 class Place(models.Model):
      user=models.ForeignKey(User)
      mall=models.ForeignKey(Fin)
      full_name=models.CharField(max_length=100)
      e_mail=models.EmailField(max_length=100)
      phone_no=models.CharField(max_length=100)
      pub_date=models.DateTimeField()

      def __unicode__(self):
          return self.full_name
      class Meta:
         ordering=['-pub_date']

  class PlaceForm(ModelForm):
       class Meta:
         model=Place
         fields=('full_name','e_mail','phone_no')
         exclude=('user','pub_date','mall')
```

Views:

```
   def place_me(request):
       if request.method=="POST":
          form=PlaceForm(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
             data=form.cleaned_data
             newbooks=Place(
                 user=request.user,
                 pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(),
                 mall=Fin.objects.get(name),
                 full_name=data['full_name'],
                 e_mail=data['e_mail'],
                 phone_no=data['phone_no'])
             newbooks.save()
             return HttpResponse('Thanks for choosing themall, we will contact you as soon as possible. Go grab a beer :)')
         else:
            return HttpResponse('Some fields are not filled correctly')
     else:
        return render_to_response('buuk.html',{'PlaceForm':PlaceForm},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line `mall=Fin.objects.get(name)` you have not declared the `name` variable any where in your view `place_me`, hence it is undefined.

Also the way you are passing argument in `.get` is wrong, it has to be like this:

```
mall=Fin.objects.get(name='any name')
# or you can do
mall=Fin.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Comment: I don't know the name the user will choose, that's why I want django to pick up up automatically.

Comment: @picomon By using an undeclared variable wont solve your problem. Aamir showed you how to achieve what you want